# ASP.Net WEB API Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I wrote my WEBAPI code to get some data to authinticated users, I faced multible issues and it is solved. but now I face issue when I tried to get list of data for authinticated user chrome give me this error

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.10.95/KS.API.Client/api/Data. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

aAnd this is who I called WebApi methor from pure html page

```
$.ajax({
                    url: domain + '/api/Data',
                    type: 'GET',
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        debugger;
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", " Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("Token"));
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $.each(response, function () {
                            $('#myTable').append(
                                '<tr><td>'
                                + this.username
                                + '</td><td>'
                                + this.password +
                                '</td></tr>'
                            );
                        });
                        // response
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

Please lep me

Comment: You need to enable the CORS in the web api. Please read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

In your WebAPI, you need to install package Microsoft.Owin.Cors.
Open Nuget Package Console, type this

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

After install adding reference, you need to go to Startup.cs add this line `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`
into your Configuration function
It will looks something like this

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your web.config file of your Web API in order to enable access:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This should be placed inside system.webServer node of your web.config.

Please read official documentation in order to properly use and control access from outside using CORS